# Current page location via REQUEST_URI

Tags: php

So, I want to split the `REQUEST_URI` in to pieces

Lets say I have a `REQUEST_URI` like this: `/core/info/rules/`
And want to display it like this: `Core » Info » Rules`

Any help or examples are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$uri=trim($uri,'/');
$uri=str_replace("/"," >> ",$uri);
$uri=ucwords($uri);
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/9L62gCDT)**

Comment: You could lose the extra str_replace by doing `str_replace('/', ' » ', $uri);` right away.

Answer (score 0):

Strip the first and last slash with `trim()` and then `str_replace` the leftover slashes with a right guillemet (`&raquo;` in HTML).

Answer (score 0):

you can use str_replace function for this task..

```
i.e: `str_replace("/",">>","/core/info/rules/");`
```

Try this..Its may helpfull to you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably throw it into an array so you can iterate over it, add links to the navigation, etc

```
$nav = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
array_shift($nav); // to remove the initial empty record
```